# Error: Expected the reducer to be a function - MERN app

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, environment-variables, mern

I am working on a MERN app, the code is deployed on Heroku and works fine. But since I added the ternary operator for the production build in my store.js it stopped working in development.

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import rootReducer from "./reducers/Layout"

const initialState = {}

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer, 
    initialState, 
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
        (
            (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ? 
             compose : 
            (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose)
        )
    )
)

export default store
```

I import my rootReducer from my Layout.js (index.js replacement) but it worked fine untill I added the ternary operator. But just in case here is my combineReducers function in my Layout.js.

**Layout.js (index.js replacement)**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux"
import RuleReducer from "./RuleReducer"
import ErrorReducer from "./ErrorReducer"
import AuthReducer from "./AuthReducer"

export default combineReducers({
    rule: RuleReducer,
    error: ErrorReducer,
    auth: AuthReducer
})
```

Comment: _"But since I added the ternary operator..."_ - Then you already know where you have to look for the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke so I was either blind or a fool but thanks to Andreas who commented on my question i just modified my ternary operator for anyone experiancing the same issue here is the modification:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import rootReducer from "./reducers/Layout"

const initialState = {}

const middleware = [thunk]

const stage = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ? compose : (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer, 
    initialState, 
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
        stage
    )
)

export default store
```